# PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "person" violates not-null constraint when trying class-based projection

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I cannot solve my problem, although following a documentation regarding class-based projection.
I always get the following error message:

```
PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "person" violates not-null constraint
```

This is my entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="incomeoutgo", schema = "public")
public class IncomeOutgo extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name ="id")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name="dayofweek")
    private Date dayofweek;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min= 2, max= 100)
    @Column(name="position")
    private String position;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 5, max = 50)
    @Column(name ="person")
    private String person;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min= 1)
    @Column(name="income")
    private double income;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min= 2)
    @Column(name="outgo")
    private double outgo;
}
```

So does my Repository look like:

```
@Repository
public interface ChooseMonthRepository extends JpaRepository<IncomeOutgo, Date> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT dayofweek, person, position, income, outgo FROM IncomeOutgo WHERE dayofweek >= :start_dayofmonth AND dayofweek <= :end_dayofmonth", nativeQuery = true)
    List<DateChoiceDTO> findAllByDate(@Param("start_dayofmonth") Date start_dayofmonth, @Param("end_dayofmonth") Date end_dayofmonth);
}
```

This is my class-based projection

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class DateChoiceDTO {
    Date dayofweek;
    String person;
    String position;
    double income;
    double outgo;
}
```

The Service class

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public class DateChoiceService {

    private final ChooseMonthRepository incomeOutgoDateChoice;

    public List<?> getAllForDateChoice(Date start_dayofmonth) {
        Date lastDayOfMonth=java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

        return incomeOutgoDateChoice.findAllByDate(start_dayofmonth, lastDayOfMonth);
    }
}
```

And last but not least my Controller

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Controller
@Validated
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public class DateChoiceController {

    private static final String DATE_CHOICE_VIEW = "DateChoice";

    private final DateChoiceService dateChoiceService;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String homeInit(Model model) {
        return DATE_CHOICE_VIEW;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/")
    public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("incomeoutgo") @Valid DateChoiceDTO dateChoice, Model model, @NotNull BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return DATE_CHOICE_VIEW;
        }
        List<?> incomeOutgoList = dateChoiceService.getAllForDateChoice(dateChoice.getDayofweek());
        model.addAttribute(DATE_CHOICE_VIEW, incomeOutgoList);

        return DATE_CHOICE_VIEW;
    }
}
```

I do not understand why the person column suddenly comes into play?

Maybe someone can tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: How does the executed SQL look like?

Comment: This is the sql statement: 

insert 
        into
            public.incomeoutgo
            (dayofweek, income, outgo, person, position, id) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

I just want to pass a selected date and then return all rows that are within start and a calculated end date.

Comment: And where does this insert statement come from?

Comment: You are right. I had it wrong in the Thymeleaf template. 
This is how it looks now

<form action="#" th:action="@{/}" method="post" onsubmit="return checkForm(this);">

The controller

    public String passDate(@RequestParam Date selectionDate, 

Service

public List<?> getAllForDateChoice(Date start_dayofmonth)

Repo

List<DateChoiceDTO> findAllByDate(Date start_dayofmonth, Date end_dayofmonth);

Comment: This is the error that I get now.
I am pretty sure it has something to do with the Date object.

Controller

passDate(Date selectionDate, \@ModelAttribute("datechoice") \@Valid DateChoiceDTO dateChoice, Model model, \@NotNull BindingResult bindingResult) {

Repo

\@Query(value = "SELECT dayofweek, person, position, income, outgo FROM IncomeOutgo WHERE dayofweek >= :start_dayofmonth and dayofweek <= :end_dayofmonth", nativeQuery = true)

No converter found capable of converting from type AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap to type DateChoiceDTO

I use sql.Date

Comment: @bernd I tried to solve your issue, can you please see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting following exception because the framework is not sure what to do with the tuple.

```
No converter found capable of converting from type AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap to type DateChoiceDTO
```

You have to use fully qualified name of the class when you are using construction result set mapping in the query like below:

```sql
select new a.b.cSomeDto(t.property1, t.property2) from table t
```

Here is how i have fixed it:

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT new com.example.samplejdbctemplatecall.DateChoiceDTO" +
"(table.dayofweek, table.person, table.position, table.income, table.outgo) " +
"FROM IncomeOutgo table WHERE table.dayofweek >= :start_dayofmonth AND table.dayofweek <= :end_dayofmonth")
List<DateChoiceDTO> findAllByDateSecond(@Param("start_dayofmonth") Date start_dayofmonth, @Param("end_dayofmonth") Date end_dayofmonth);
```

But as mentioned by Simon, if you have insert query firing from somewhere else you need to fix that first, because this is a complete retrieval operation and the error you are facing is related to data insertion.
Entire working sample(+ interface projection):

```java
@RequestMapping("/test")
@RestController
class IncomeOutgoController {
    private final ChooseMonthRepository chooseMonthRepository;
    private int days = 0;

    @Autowired
    IncomeOutgoController(ChooseMonthRepository chooseMonthRepository) {
        this.chooseMonthRepository = chooseMonthRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/interface-projection")
    public Object interfaceProjection() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
        Date date = calendar.getTime();
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        return composeResponse("interface-projection", chooseMonthRepository.findAllByDate(date, calendar.getTime()));
    }

    @GetMapping("/constructor-projection")
    public Object constructorProjection() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
        Date date = calendar.getTime();
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        return composeResponse("constructor-projection", chooseMonthRepository.findAllByDateSecond(date, calendar.getTime()));
    }


    @GetMapping("/store")
    public Object addRandomData() {
        String randomUuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        chooseMonthRepository.save(new IncomeOutgo(null, Calendar.getInstance().getTime(), "random-position: " + randomUuid,
                randomUuid, new Random(5000).nextDouble(), new Random(500).nextDouble()));
        return "success";
    }

    private Map<String, Object> composeResponse(String key, Object value) {
        final Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put(key, value);
        return response;
    }

}

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "incomeoutgo", schema = "public")
class IncomeOutgo extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "dayofweek")
    private Date dayofweek;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 100)
    @Column(name = "position")
    private String position;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 5, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "person")
    private String person;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1)
    @Column(name = "income")
    private double income;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2)
    @Column(name = "outgo")
    private double outgo;
}

@Repository
interface ChooseMonthRepository extends JpaRepository<IncomeOutgo, Date> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT dayofweek, person, position, income, outgo FROM IncomeOutgo WHERE dayofweek >= :start_dayofmonth AND dayofweek <= :end_dayofmonth", nativeQuery = true)
    List<DateChoiceDTOInterface> findAllByDate(@Param("start_dayofmonth") Date start_dayofmonth, @Param("end_dayofmonth") Date end_dayofmonth);


    @Query(value = "SELECT new com.example.samplejdbctemplatecall.DateChoiceDTO" +
            "(table.dayofweek, table.person, table.position, table.income, table.outgo) " +
            "FROM IncomeOutgo table WHERE table.dayofweek >= :start_dayofmonth AND table.dayofweek <= :end_dayofmonth")
    List<DateChoiceDTO> findAllByDateSecond(@Param("start_dayofmonth") Date start_dayofmonth, @Param("end_dayofmonth") Date end_dayofmonth);
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
class DateChoiceDTO {
    Date dayofweek;
    String person;
    String position;
    Double income;
    Double outgo;
}

interface DateChoiceDTOInterface {
    Date getDayOfWeek();

    String getPerson();

    String getPosition();

    Double getIncome();

    Double getOutgo();
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://172.17.0.2:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=mysecretpassword
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```